# Disable authentication in App Center Distribute

Tags: ios, visual-studio-app-center, visual-studio-app-center-distribute

According to [App Center Distribute – In-app updates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/distribute/ios)

> Once the app is installed and opened for the first time after the App
>   Center Distribute SDK has been added, a browser will open to enable
>   in-app updates. This is a one time step that will not occur for
>   subsequent releases of your app.

Is it possible to prevent the browser opening / disable the user  authentication?

Comment: I have the same question. Have you found an answer yet?

Comment: Anything at all?

Comment: I think the "Distribute" module only works with user authentication, judging by looking at the REST API (other than HockeyApp, where notification of new app versions didn't require authentication). Of course one can remove the Distribute module, but that's probably not what you want?